# Installation issues - unmet dependencies

Tags: installation, developer

trying to install the civicrm buildkit using the instructions found here : 
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/

I am on ubuntu 16.04. 
When I run `curl -Ls https://civicrm.org/get-buildkit.sh | bash -s -- --full --dir ~/buildkit` I get the error:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 nodejs-legacy : Depends: nodejs (>= 0.6.19~dfsg1-3~) but it is not going to be installed
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My nodejs version is v11.2.0 (I tried to update to fix this issue). I have tried removing it and reinstalling it. I have done a `sudo apt autoremove`. I'm not sure what else to try here. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: This is a good question to ask in the ~dev-newcomers channel on https://chat.civicrm.org.

Answer (score 1):

The command you're running, on Ubuntu 16.04, attempts to install the `nodejs-legacy` package.  As it says, it can't because it relies on a particular version of `nodejs` that won't be installed.

So first - this problem should be replicable with a simple `sudo apt install nodejs-legacy`, which simplifies the variables and takes CiviCRM out of the equation.  It's probably even replicable with `sudo apt install nodejs`.

Second, it sounds like you have something installed - perhaps a newer version of nodejs? - that's preventing an installation of the packaged version of `nodejs`.

After removing nodejs, try running `dpkg -l | grep nodejs` and see what, if any packages are installed.

Alternatively, removing `--full` from your command will disable attempting to autoinstall packages.  If your environment is a good one, this should work fine.  You can review the packages you need installed in [this part of the script](https://civicrm.org/get-buildkit.sh).